# Create PHP array out of table column

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a loop that displays each row in a table. I think I need to make an array out of the PK, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Here is my code so far:

```
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$getData = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$allData = $conn->query($getdata);
if (!$allData) {
    $error = $conn->error;
} else {
    $data = $allData->fetch_assoc();
    $rowId = array($data['PK']);
} while ($rowId <= count($rowId)) {
    // code to be run for each row
    $rowId++;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry my question is confusing, I'm new to PHP.

Comment: you know that fetch_assoc() only fetches _one row after each other_?

Comment: Julio: It is not called PK, but it is an auto-increment integer. Jeff: I did not know that.  What would you suggest instead?

Comment: your aren't including the $row inside the while and your are "calling" and array "2 times" with the fetch assoc and then array (). Look at my answer.

Comment: Why would you want to capture just a generated surrogate key? It sounds like there is another problem you're trying to solve which you haven't told us about which you are trying to fix the wrong way.

Comment: side note: `table` isn't the actual name for it, is it?

Comment: symcbean: I have other code to run in each instance of this loop, but I may be going about it the wrong way.  Funk Forty Niner: No, I changed the names to be more general for my post.

Comment: @symcbean I'm agree.

Comment: @Ethameshep: the only thing I can imagine you using a surrogate key in a loop for is to run more queries - which is completely wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['PK']] = $row;
}
```

That would iterate over each row, creating an array and using the row's value for column `PK` as an associative array key.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch_assoc()` (I assume mysqli here now) doesn't fetch *all data* from a result, but one row after each other. So you don't need to make an array of `$row['PK']`, but need to loop over the results.

```
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$getData = 'SELECT * FROM `table`'; // you would need backticks here, if the table really is called "table" (what you shouldn't do...)
$result = $conn->query($getData); // it's not 'allData', it is a result_set. And be carefull about Case! $getData!=$getdata
if (!$result) {
    $error = $conn->error;
} else {
    $cnt=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // code to be run for each row
        // you can display $row['PK'] now:
        echo $row['PK'];
        // or add that value to something else, whatever you need
        $cnt = $cnt+$row['PK'];
        // or to have a new array with the values of one table-column:
        $columnRows[] = $row['PK'];
    }
    // now you can use the created array
    foreach($columnRows as $PK) {
        echo $PK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at these 2 lines: $getData = 'SELECT * FROM table';
                              $result = $conn->query($getdata); $getData != $getdata.

Comment: Thanks. copy&paste from the OP... I didn't see it.

Comment: you could have adapted it. It's not a conquest here! We just need to make sure our answers are correct.

Comment: Yeah but without codeigniter I would ended doing the same as @billynoah in his answer and we can repeat an answer lol